# Probability of a path matrix from weighted adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, graph-theory

Given a graph adjacency matrix $A$, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860272/computation-of-path-matrix-from-the-adjacency-matrix)  shows how to calculate the path matrix from it.

I am interested in a generalisation of this. Let $A$ be a weighted adjacency matrix, where $A_{ij}$ represents the probability of an edge existing between vertex $i$ and $j$. Is there an efficient way to calculate the "probability of a path" matrix $P$ such that $P_{ij}$ represents the probability of a path existing between vertex $i$ and $j$ (other than a sum over $2^{k}$ objects where $k$ is the number of potential edges in the graph)?

Clearly if $A$ consists of only $0$s and $1$s, then the "probability of a path" and path matrix, are the same.